# I want to write a code that creates more than one User in Facebook . Is it possible?

Tags: facebook

I am a newbie in facebook programming . But i know something about Java and Java EE.
I would like to do such a programming that will create multiple user account and then all of the users will give a like in a certain facebook page or give comments in a facebook fan page.
Is it possible ? How do I access facebook tables to insert/update ? It would be better if this could be done in Java . I will also like other language if Java is not the correct language here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook api is language agnostic, that is it works with http requests and so you can implement that in any language that supports http requests.

There are some SDKs for different languages, such as the official javascript, php, iOS and android SDKs, and there are other ones (unofficial) for java, C#, actionscript, etc.

I can't say I completely understand what you want to do, but there's no way to create a facebook user with the graph api.
You have no insert/update access to any facebook table (using FQL), only selecting.

You can add/change data using the graph api, but you need an authenticated user who granted your app the right permissions.

If you want to automate creating of fictional facebook profiles which will then "like" a page/url then you can't do that.

Comment: Thank you so much it was very useful . Actually what i want is to create multuple facebook users through my webpage .ie, i will have a form in my website , and when a user hits the "create new user" button this account creation information will send request in facebook and an account will be created in facebook .

Comment: If you have a facebook app and would like to create users for testing that specific app, then you have a way to create [Test Users](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) by issuing a http request, and so that can be done in the scenario you described. If however you wish to create real facebook users then no, you can not do that.